# SSIS script task to get file Name and Creation date of Text File

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a text file in two forms of extension .cos and .rcs. I have imported the content into of all the .cos and .rcs files from a directory (about 100 textfiles) a sql table using for each loop Container.

[image]
However, I think I have skipped a step to get the file name and creation date, I tried to get the name of the file using a derived table but its half worked as it only does it for one file. But from reading online, the only way to get the creation date is to do a script task. However if I need to go down that route you can get the filename and creation date by using script task. I was wondering if someone can help me to accomplish this using the script task function. Thank you

Comment: how you structured the loop ? did you use global variables ?

Comment: The best way to get that information will be determined what you will do with the filename and creation date when you are done.  Add to a table? Move the Files? What format do you wan it in as you recurse through the directories, in a dataset??.... System.IO.FileInfo and System.IO.DirectoryInfo classes will be useful to you.